# Route/Forward between 2 Openvpn tunnels/NICS

Tags: linux, firewall, routing

[image: e]

I have this simple network with 3 Servers.
Server1 has an openvpn tunnel with S2 and another ovpn tunnel with S3.
What i want is that S1 can talk with S2 by using both tunnels and also vice verca.

How can i set this up properly?
I already tried it with iptables but it didnt work.
I think i got the commands wrong or sth.
What would be the commands (linux iptables) to "connect" the tunnels so that traffic incoming tun1 can be forwarded to tun2 and vice versa ?

Comment: Routers route packets between networks. You either need physical routers to do that, or you need to run routing on your servers.

Comment: This is a bit tricky.  For  a start you should not be using 11.x addresses.   Can you advise the netmasks and configs.   There are a mindfield of things, including enabling routing, handling NAT, OpenVPN server config with networks.   Also, any particular reason you have a tun on 10.100 and on 11.100 rather then just 1 subnet so OpenVPN can do internal routing

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc5ff.png)

I hope this pictures makes things clearer.

The connection from S4 to S2 is working by using OpenVPN Tunnel 1 to connect to S1 and redirect over OpenVPN Tunnel 2 to S2.
I made it work with these commands:

sudo iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface tun0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface tun1 -j MASQUERADE

And Iptables:
sudo ip rule add from 10.200.0.6 table 1 prio 32760
sudo ip route add "192.168.4.1" table 1 via "10.100.0.2" dev tun1

But unfortunately I cant make it work so that S2 and S3 can communicate with each other.
What commands do i need, what i tried isnt working.

Comment: You should edit a question instead of giving additional info in an answer. Still, based on that info, I would ask you why so many tunnels, that is much work, why don't you use a single client-server OpenVPN network with four clients and let OpenVPN route internally as @davidgo suggested?

Comment: its for a bigger project and the tunnels are needed for security reasons...

Comment: then there is much more pressure to avoid using 11.x addresses. Because this block is owned by USA Department of Defence: https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-11-0-0-0-1 . You only can freely these blocks and everything else either is reserved or is owned by someone: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses